# PHP7 Fatal error: Declaration of... must be compatible with

Tags: neo4j, php-7

I've installed PHP 7 and have setup demo example from https://github.com/graphaware/reco4php but struggling with following error .I am not much familiar with PHP 7 , can anybody help me please?

```
Fatal error: Declaration of GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Demo\Github\RecommendationEngine::discoveryEngines() must be compatible with GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Engine\RecommendationEngine::discoveryEngines(): array in /var/www/html/reco-fresh/_demo/github/RecommendationEngine.php on line 5
```

**Class :** RecommendationEngine.php has following codes -

```
namespace GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Demo\Github;

class RecommendationEngine extends \GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Engine\BaseRecommendationEngine
{
    public function discoveryEngines()
    {
        return array(
            new FollowedByFollowers(),
            new SameContribution()
        );
    }    
}
```

**Interface :** RecommendationEngine

```
namespace GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Engine;

use GraphAware\Common\Type\Node;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Context\Context;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Persistence\DatabaseService;

interface RecommendationEngine
{
    public function name() : string;

    public function discoveryEngines() : array;
}
```

**Abstract class :** - BaseRecommendationEngine

```
namespace GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Engine;

use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Context\Context;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Executor\RecommendationExecutor;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Filter\BlackListBuilder;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Filter\Filter;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Persistence\DatabaseService;
use GraphAware\Common\Type\Node;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Post\PostProcessor;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Result\Recommendations;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

abstract class BaseRecommendationEngine implements RecommendationEngine
{
    private $databaseService;

    private $recommendationExecutor;

    public function discoveryEngines() : array
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you perhaps missing one `: array`?

Comment: How to use : array ? do you have any reference link where I can read more about it ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak PHP at all, but all the other functions were declared as `function functionName () : array`, but yours isn't.

Comment: It seems this is new feature added in php 7 , but not sure.Anyways thanks for you response.

Answer (score 1):

You cab find the answer to your question here : [Neo4j - Graphaware reco4php - Problem with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429823/neo4j-graphaware-reco4php-problem-with-namespaces)

When you extend the class you should specify the type of "return" after the definition of the function:

```
public function name() : string 
{
return "rated_by_others";
}
```